# merge dataframe to create grouped time series

Tags: r, merge, time-series

I want to create a grouped time series (hierarchal structure). Essentially for every year there are four quarters and 12 months. Year is Grand Total, Quarters are subtotals of months. Month is the bottom values. I am trying to use `gts` of `hts` library by Robert Handyman (`forecast`): [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/gts.html), But I am missing something somewhere. Preliminary demo data is shown below.

```
library(tidyr)
```

table1:

```
ts(rnorm(67),  start=c(2015, 4),frequency=12)
```

table 2:

```
aggregate(ts(rnorm(67),  start=c(2015, 4), frequency=12), nfrequency=4)
```

Any advise how to create a column as a grand total of year, and then aggregate by quarter, and represent months. These will essentially meant that, there are hierarchy of year-quarter-month on the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wedded to sticking with the `ts()` format, you could put it in a dataset and use functions from `zoo`, `lubridate` and `dplyr` to make your required output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
x <- ts(rnorm(67),  start=c(2015, 4),frequency=12)
dat <- tibble(
  # change time of the ts object into year-month 
  # and extract just the month 
  m = month(as.yearmon(time(x))), 
  # change time of the ts object to year-month
  # and extract the year
  year = year(as.yearmon(time(x))), 
  # change time of the ts object to year-month
  # and extract the quarter
  qtr = quarter(as.yearmon(time(x))),
  value = as.vector(x)) %>% 
  # group data by year and quarter
  group_by(year, qtr) %>% 
  # get the sum of value for each year-quarter.
  mutate(qtr_sum = sum(value)) %>% 
  # ungroup the data and then group again just by year
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  # calculate the yearly sum 
  mutate(yr_sum = sum(value))

dat
# # A tibble: 67 x 6
# # Groups:   year [6]
#     m   year   qtr   value qtr_sum yr_sum
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     4  2015     2  0.555  -1.68   -0.851
# 2     5  2015     2 -0.767  -1.68   -0.851
# 3     6  2015     2 -1.47   -1.68   -0.851
# 4     7  2015     3 -1.75   -0.0733 -0.851
# 5     8  2015     3  1.26   -0.0733 -0.851
# 6     9  2015     3  0.408  -0.0733 -0.851
# 7    10  2015     4 -0.0731  0.905  -0.851
# 8    11  2015     4  0.824   0.905  -0.851
# 9    12  2015     4  0.154   0.905  -0.851
# 10     1  2016     1 -0.231  -0.634   2.70 
# # … with 57 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks DaveArmstrong, but this problem demands hierarchical structure of time series. Any thoughts?

Comment: @lpt I'm not sure.  It looks from my reading like the `hts()` and `gts()` functions are meant for the hierarchy to be something other than time - like a total that is decomposed into parts across groups (like Male and Female).  It's not clear to me in that framework how you would handle the grouping you're talking about.

Comment: yes, generally you are correct. However, Quarter is combination of months,